# Interchange limit and sum in power series

Tags: power-series, uniform-convergence, analytic-functions

Suppose $(f_n)_n$ are analytic functions with power series representation
$$
f_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{2k}^n (x-x_0)^{2k}, \qquad x \in [a,b].
$$
Notice that for every $f_n$, all odd powers vanish in this representation.
Suppose further that the $(f_n)_n$ converge uniformly on $[a,b]$ to a function $f$. Then $f$ is analytic, i.e. there are $(b_k)_k$ such that
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k (x-x_0)^k, \qquad x \in [a,b].
$$

Is it true that all odd powers vanish as well, i.e. is $b_{2k+1} = 0$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: You should not use $x_k$ in the second line , but $y_k.$ You already have a diifferent $x_k$ in the first line.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to $a^n_k$ and $b_k.$

Comment: Putting $u=x-x_0$, your condition is that $f_n(-u)=f_n(u)$ for $|u|<r$, for some $r>0$. Of course we have $f(-u)=f(u)$, hence the result.

Comment: Yes. But how long it takes to show it may depend on your background. Are you familiar with the Hadamard radius formula and its proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g_n(x-x_0)=f_n(x).$ Let $g(x-x_0)=f(x).$ Then $g_n(y)=f_n(y+y_0)=f_n(-y-y_0)=g_n(-y).$ Therefore  $g(y)=g(-y).$

So if $g(y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_ny^n$ then $$f(y+y_0)=g(y)=(g(y)+g(-y))/2=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}a_{2m}y^{2m}.$$ $$\text {So }\quad f(y)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}a_{2m}(y-y_0)^{2m}.$$

If $a< b$ then the sequence of co-efficients is unique: If $\sum_n a_n(y-x_0)^n=\sum_na'_n(y-y_0)^n$  for all $y\in [a,b]$ then  $a_n=a'_n$ for every  $n$.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great answer! Bonus question: If $a^n_{2k} \ge 0$ for all $k, n$, is it also true that $b_k \ge 0$ for all $k$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true. Let $k$ be an odd natural number. Then$$b_k=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{f(u)}{(u-z_0)^{k+1}}\,du=\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{f_n(u)}{(u-z_0)^{k+1}}\,du\text,$$
where $\gamma(t)=z_0+re^{it}$ ($t\in[0,2\pi]$), for some small $r$. Since $k$ is odd, $k+1$ is even and so the Laurent series of $f_n$ near $z_0$ has no term of the type $(z-z_0)^{-1}$ (or, to be more precise, its coefficient is $0$). Therefore,$$\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{f_n(u)}{(u-z_0)^{k+1}}\,du=0.$$